# Idiomatic expression for temporarily removing key-value pairs from a dictionary in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

See title: the general idea is:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'b': 3}
print(d.without('b', 'c'))  # {'a': 1}
print(d)  # {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'b': 3}
```

With the assumption that `without`'s signature is `(*keys)`

Comment: Can you use a dictionary-comprehension to remove items from dictionary?

Comment: I'm benchmarking `filter` versus a conditional comprehension now

Comment: You should probably control for the size of the dictionary -- the perf cost of duplicating a larger piece of memory are likely to outweigh the relative costs of executing the logic.

Comment: @theodox it's not a large amount of information, but this operation is repeated several hundred times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is use a dictionary comprehension so as to create a temporary dictionary:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'b': 3}
print({ key : value for key, value in d.items() if key not in ('b','c')})
print(d)
```

Output

```
{'a': 1}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'b': 3}
```

Comment: Both are going to be O(n).

Comment: From the filter python page: `Note that filter(function, iterable) is equivalent to [item for item in iterable if function(item)] if function is not None and [item for item in iterable if item] if function is None.`

Answer (score 3):

A dict comprehension is a good way to pull out a subset of keys and make a new dictionary, whether you want to keep or remove items:

```
def only_keys(dictionary, *keys):
     allowed = set(keys)
     return { k: v for k, v in dictionary.iteritems() if k in allowed }

def without_keys(dictionary, *keys):
     prohibited = set(keys)
     return { k: v for k, v in dictionary.iteritems() if k not in prohibited }
```

If the dictionary is small -- or if runtime perf is not a critical problem -- this is probably simpler than changing the dictionary and changing it back again.

If the dictionary is really big it might be better to filter the whole dictionary on the fly so you don't incur the memory cost of copying it all (again rather than removing items and replacing them).  Something like this would give you the key-value pairs in the dictionary that matched your list of keys without creating a whole new dictionary

```
 def filter_dict(dictionary, *allowed_keys):
     allowed = set(allowed_keys)
     for k, v in dictionary.iteritems():
         if k in allowed:
            yield k, v
```

Iterating over the result of that will give you all the key-value pairs in the original dictionary with an allowed key (the inverse would work the same way except it would be `not in` as in the earlier examples.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a dictionary-comprehension to filter out dictionary items based on condition. This creates a new dictionary, preserving the old one:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'b': 3}
print({k: v for k, v in d.items() if k not in ['b', 'c']})  # {'a': 1}
print(d)  # {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'b': 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could subclass dict...

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def without(self, *keys):
        return MyDict({k:v for k,v in self.items() if k not in keys})


d = MyDict(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)
print(d.without('a', 'c')) #{'b': 2, 'd': 4}
```

Comment: While this answers the question's example _technically_, I suppose I should specify I would like to avoid subclassing